# Apps Script -> error loading iframe form over main page due to browser update

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe

Few weeks ago my application runs perfectly on every browser known today, but when google chrome, edge and firefox updated to latest version my app turns over fails when it tries to load a form inside an iframe.

My application is written in google apps script (.gs), so i have defined this codeline when i have to call an iframe:

```
return template.evaluate().setTitle('GPS - Visor Gestión de Solicitudes - Desarrollo').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

The setXframeOptionsMode sentence set as above is assumed to be correct. i don't know why latest version for chrome doesn't show the iframe. it works in Browsers like Opera and Safari.

this is a snapshot from app working fine:

[image]

after browsers updating:

[image]

Comment: Which version of the chrome browser are you using?

Comment: I've been using Chrome v90  and firefox v87 (app fails upon these browser versions)

Comment: Can you post the rest of the template? I can't reproduce your issue.